# Is there a way to reduce multiple comparison with similar parameters?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using php as backend of a website. I made a form of around 50 questions and I have to store it in a table every single time I answer something different.

So my first newbie thought was to compare the `$request->Question1` with the `$table->Question1` and if this is different, I create a new record on the `History` table.

But it took my to an endless and nothing good looking comparison lines, repeating some of the code like:

```
 if ($table->Question1 != $request->Question1)
                {
                $Question = new HistoryTable();
                $Question ->reason = 'Change Answer';
                $Question ->column_affected = 'Question1';
                $Question ->old_value = $table->Question1;
                $Question ->new_value = $request->Question1;
                $Question ->created_at = Carbon::now();
                $Question ->save();
            }
```

Is there a way it could be reduced ? I was thinking in using a form, but I have to mention I have columns/values as Question23_1 and Question23_2 ... but they are the same name as in table

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're really asking several questions, and since it involves a database it gets even more complex. You really should [provide a minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), as your database schema already looks very inefficient. At the very least, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27533810) to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish and what's not currently working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some might suggest a different database-table architecture – one that does not involve these "repeating groups."  But there might be other compelling reasons to have done what you did.

Maybe you could retrieve the record, instead of as a "PHP object," as an array *("hash" ...)* indexed by field-name.  Then you could use interpolation of strings such as `"Question$x_$y"` ... substituting the values of `$x` and `$y` to obtain the name of the field whose value you are now interested in ...